# How change background color when user slide his finger on layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I created a LinearLayout with four items inside of it. I want to change the backgrounds of inside items when user`s finger slide on them.
How should I implement onTouchEvent?

For example, when user touch mail linear layout and move finger on items, background of item changed...

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/letters_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_letter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_margin="2dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="A"
                    android:textSize="50sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_letter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_margin="2dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="B"
                    android:textSize="50sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

thanks for help...

Comment: If you  touched `first_letter` ,`first_letter` background changed.Did you want to do this? If you wanted do this,you can use `selector.xml`.

Comment: @KeLiuyue I want touch rootView and move finger over first_letter and after that change the background of first_letter, and then move to second letter and change the background of it